# Database query to select the maximum row with user_id

Tags: codeigniter

i need to select the maximum database entry row from the table with the `user_id`

table name: `cd_production`

```
code_cd  etaireia  etos
______________________
400400  ODEON     1987
400401  ODEON     1986
400412  COLUMBIA  1990
400420  COLUMBIA  1990
400657  LYRA      1965
410000  COLUMBIA  1962
410001  COLUMBIA  1964
410003  PHILIPS   1979
410005  PHILIPS   1971
420430  ODEON     2002
420440  LYRA      2005
420450  COLUMBIA  2009
420460  ODEON     2007
420470  PHILIPS   2008
420480  ODEON     2002
420490  COLUMBIA  2010
500500  SONY      1968
500510  SONY      1972
600601  COLUMBIA  1962
600602  COLUMBIA  1963
600603  ODEON     1964
670670  PHILIPS   1983
asad
```

Comment: Question doesn't make sense. You don't appear to have a user_id column

Comment: i forget to copy,again i tried but i cant

Comment: do you have experience in opencart ,then help me how to install vq mod in new version

Comment: Tried to copy what? If you want help around here you need to put more effort into asking and clarifying questions.

Comment: sorry ! dont get angry

Comment: That's not being angry...is stating fact only. Properly created questions generally get answered fast here

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
    $result=this->db->query("select max(user_id) as maxValue form tableName")->result_array();
    $maxValue=$result[0]['maxValue']; //or $result['maxValue']; 
    echo $maxValue;
  $result2=this->db->query("select * from tableName user user_id=$maxValue")->result_array();

var_dump($result2);
```